# Implement Voice Recognization in worklight using nuance?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, voice

ING Bankerian Nederlads implement voice based money payment in their Mobile bank application using Integration of IBM worklight with nuance Voice services. Info link:
http://www.tweaktown.com/news/46744/ing-netherlands-introduces-voice-based-mobile-payments/index.html.

I want to know how to use nuance voice service in worklight. Please provide appropriate documentation on Integration of IBM worklight with nuance Voice services. Other than nuance is there any other services available to implement voice based mobile apps using worklight.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you need to do:

1. Google for "nuance voice service" and visit their website.
2. Click on "For Developers"
3. Click on "More About Nuance Mobile Developer SDK"
4. Optionally click on "Get Started", register
5. Scroll down and click on "Documentation"
6. There you get SDK download links.
7. Scroll a bit more, and you have a link to GitHub for instructions, with images and code samples.

Bottom line - we can't do it for you. First do Something yourself.